# RxJS wait for previous execution to finish

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Ok, so I'm new to RxJs and I can't figure out some thing.
I need to implement image processing in which the user adds multiple images at a time and for each image, among others, following actions must occur:

1. Generate the image thumbnail in the web worker
2. Upload the image and a thumbnail to the server

But I don't want all thumbnails to be generated at once, I'd like them to generate sequentially. Here's what I tried: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-mountain-tm0jj?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14

I'll also paste the code here:

```js
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

const imageObservable = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

function generateThumbnail(image) {
  console.log(`Generating thumbnail ${image}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Finished generating thumbnail ${image}`);
      resolve({
        image,
        thumbnail: `This is a thumbnail of image ${image}`
      });
    }, 1500);
  });
}

async function upload(imagePromise) {
  const image = await imagePromise;
  console.log("Uploading", image);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Finished uploading", image);
      resolve();
    }, 1500);
  });
}

imageObservable.pipe(map(generateThumbnail)).subscribe(upload);
```

I'd like RxJS to wait for previous `generateThumbnail` in order to perform current call (that's why it returns a promise object) and also wait for previous `upload` in order to perform the current one (so `upload` is also returning promise). I have no idea how to achieve that. Any RxJS ninja would like to help me with that?

Comment: does the generateThumbnail should wait for the previous upload also ?

Comment: No, it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only want generating thumbnails to be sequential or does generation of a second thumbnail need to wait for upload of the first one to finish as well?

If you don't want to wait for upload, you just need to concat them:

```
import { of, from, } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const imageObservable = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

function generateThumbnail(image) {
    console.log(`Generating thumbnail ${image}`);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Finished generating thumbnail ${image}`);
            resolve({
                image,
                thumbnail: `This is a thumbnail of image ${image}`
            });
        }, 1500);
    });
}

async function upload(imagePromise) {
    const image = await imagePromise;
    console.log('Uploading', image);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Finished uploading', image);
            resolve();
        }, 1500);
    });
}

// imageObservable.pipe(map(generateThumbnail)).subscribe(upload);

imageObservable.pipe(concatMap(image => from(generateThumbnail(image)))).subscribe();
```

[concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) does what you want, and I just made an `Observable` out of your `Promise` with `from` creational operator, which I don't think is needed. But it's usually easier to work with `Observables` instead of `Promises` when you use RxJs.

```
function generateThumbnail(image): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`Generating thumbnail ${image}`);
    return from(
        new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(`Finished generating thumbnail ${image}`);
                resolve({
                    image,
                    thumbnail: `This is a thumbnail of image ${image}`
                });
            }, 1500);
        })
    );
}
```

Edit:
Can you try this?

```
imageObservable
    .pipe(
        concatMap(image => generateThumbnail(image)),
        concatMap(image => upload(image))
    )
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: Cool, it looks like it could solve my problem, I'll try that, thanks a lot! Also - is it possible to make upload wait for previous one as well (i mean - previous upload)?

Comment: Can't edit comment anymore - I think that it might be possible using the same method with concatMap, but in that case the upload is the subscriber, not a filter.

Comment: Is this empty `subscribe()` call cosidered a "clean" solution?

Comment: Of course. I like to have everything in pipeable operators, it's easier extendable. I usually see `subscribe` just as "ok now execute the pipeline" and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the following:

1. Thumbnails generation should be done sequentially *order is important* => use **concatMap**
2. Upload should be done as soon as the thumbnail is generated
3. Upload can be done in parallel *order is not important* => use **map**

So the final code could be

```
imageObservable
  .pipe(
    // preserve orders and wait for previous observable
    concatMap(generateThumbnail), 

    // map the generate
    map(upload)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

> Note: upload does not wait for the generateThumbnail promise since this should be handled by concatMap itself.

```
async function upload(image) {
  console.log(`[upload] start ${image.image}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`[upload] done ${image.image}`);
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But basically this seems to be the same solution that ritaj suggested